# Is there a list of recommended reading for beginners?

Tags: learning, literature

When someone starts learning a language, there are some novels that really should be required reading (if we're going that route of learning). Esperanto has a lot of literature. Is there a list of books that one could recommend to beginners? Maybe a club has prepared a list that it recommends to newbies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esperanto USA Beginner Book List - [Website](https://esperanto-usa.org/en/content/recommended-books-beginners)

This is my video response to your question - [Video](https://youtu.be/RUv5imr9ZWM)

Answer (score 15):

I recommend all the books by Claude Piron. I haven't read them all yet, but Claude Piron had a style very simple and rich ! He is really the author who gave me a crush on esperanto ! He was able to use all its particularities and make it so easy and subtile in the same time ! It's so delicious !
I suggest : « Lasu min paroli plu », which is written for beginners with a slow progression. Or « Dankon amiko ».
Also « Gerda malaperis » is very known but it's not my favourite !!
You can find many of them in PDF there : http://claudepiron.free.fr/livres.htm

About Esperanto itself, every esperantist should read « la bona lingvo ». But it's not for beginners.

Answer (score 8):

I personally found Ne Ekzistas Verdaj Steloj by Liven Dek ([https://www.amazon.com/Ekzistas-Verdaj-Steloj-Mikronoveloj-Esperanto/dp/1595692355](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1595692355)) to be an excellent story to help me learn Esperanto style. Although it's not as straightforward as Claude Piron's works, the stories contained in it are brief and witty, which makes them enjoyable, simple, and satisfying to read.

Answer (score 4):

In the article [start reading Esperanto literature](http://blogs.transparent.com/esperanto/start-reading-esperanto-literature/) in Chuck Smith's blog about Esperanto, literature expert Amelie Ambrus recommends Gerda Malaperis and Fajron Sentas Mi Interne to start out with and then moves on to William Auld's poetry and La Infana Raso.